# Eclipse assumed wrong encoding and changed all project files' encoding

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding

I had a Java project I was working on, of which all source code files were encoded in UTF-8, and many contained Japanese text.

I upgraded Eclipse, and opened the same workspace.

Eclipse however, instantly destroyed all my workspace's files, changing them to Eclipse's default encoding (Cp1252) and resaving them, so that:

```
String A = "カフェ"；
```

is now:

```
String A = "é£²ã�¿ç‰©";
```

What is the best way to get the files back to how they were?

Comment: Is is safe to assume you are not using some kind of source managent (aka, version control system), like git, svn, Perforce, etc?

Comment: @E-Riz I am indeed not using any version control on this project.

Comment: Eclipse would not "resave" all your files without you taking some explicit action.  The files are probably still UTF-8 encoded, but Eclipse is displaying them as if they were CP-1252.  I believe all you have to do is change Eclipse's default encoding back to UTF-8.

Comment: @JimGarrison I would normally expect this too, but if I open the files in Notepad++, I can see they are currently properly encoded in UTF-8 containing the characters as Cp1252 would decode UTF-8 (so the files now literally contain é£²ã�¿ç‰© but encoded in UTF-8). The files have all been updated at the same moment (without anything changing except them being imported in Eclipse - without moving them) so Eclipse did actually resave them all. Note: I have a variety of plugins that may have played a part in this, such as Lombok. But it has already happened, that itself I cannot reverse.

Comment: The string `é£²ã�¿ç‰©`  looks like UTF-8 being interpreted as CP1252.  I

Comment: @JimGarrison That is because it IS UTF-8 being interpreted as Cp1252. It WAS, at least, and then resaved as the same characters in UTF-8.

Comment: Have you tried setting Eclipse's default encoding back to UTF-8?

Comment: @JimGarrison Eclipse's default encoding was never set to UTF-8, I always had it in Cp1252. Eclipse also offers the option of setting an encoding per project: this was set to UTF-8. The upgraded Eclipse has loaded this correctly, I did not need to set it again.

Comment: This is highly inconsistent.  You were working on a project that was always UTF-8 but Eclipse was always CP1252? That should never have worked.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough.
* The files were saved in UTF-8
* Eclipse project settings (project -> Properties -> Resource -> Text file encoding) was always set to UTF-8
* Eclipse new project settings are set to Cp1252 (so if I create a new project, this will be the standard encoding) as also seen in "Inherited from container" in the project settings

This was true in my workspace both in my previous and new installation of Eclipse, none of those settings were modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has a [Local History feature](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-87b.htm), but it's applied at the individual file level, not the project or even folder level. You could potentially use it to restore previous versions of each file, one-by-one; unfortunately, I don't think there's a UI for doing that for entire containers (folders or projects).

I'm sure you don't need to be told at this point, but virtually every non-trivial project is worthy of storing in some kind of version control, even if it's only local.

Comment: Though this leaves me to find out which files were affected (I did not notice immediately and have made - not too many - changes since then), it is a brilliant answer; I have used Eclipse for over 5 years and had no clue this existed! I suppose there is still much to learn in the many many features it has.

Comment: As a separate comment on version control: I have been programming for over a decade and still need reminders for this. (While version control is great, it comes as natural to me as laundry.) Thank you very much!